# Cálculo de porcentagem de crescimento

Tags: php, mysql, porcentagem

Tenho três colunas que seriam *mês*, *receita* e *despesas*. Por exemplo:

```
Mês       | Receita | Despesas 
Janeiro   | 2500    | 1000 
Fevereiro | 1000    | 500
```

Gostaria de demostrar a porcentagem de crescimento utilizando PHP e MySQL.

O arquivo `.sql` está como:

```
CREATE TABLE `financas`   
  `codusuario` int (11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mes` varchar(100) NOT NULL,    
  `receitas` varchar(100) NOT NULL,    
  `despesas` text(100) NOT NULL,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`codusuario`)   
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54270/discussion-on-question-by-the-flash-calculo-de-porcentagem-de-crescimento)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solução para visualizar crescimento mensal:

Segue uma query para obter as colunas e a taxa de crescimento **mensal**
(supondo que cada linha fosse um mês).
Para períodos maiores, ou total, basta adaptar a solução para usar `SUM` e `GROUP BY` ou acumular dados em mais *@variáveis*.

```sql
SET @anterior=0;

SELECT
      id,
      receitas,
      despesas,
      @subtotal := (receitas-despesas) AS subtotal,
      IF( @anterior !=0, (@subtotal/@anterior-1)*100, '?' ) AS crescimento,
      @anterior := @subtotal
   FROM rendimentos;
```

<sub>As quebras de linha não são necessárias.</sub>

Notar que compensa fazer duas *queries* separadas, para simplificar, uma com o SET e outra com o SELECT.

O IF utilizado para calcular o crescimento faz o seguinte:

- se o valor anterior for diferente de zero, retorna a taxa de crescimento em porcentagem.
- se o valor anterior for zero, retorna `?`. Você pode substituir a `?` pelo valor que achar conveniente para sua aplicação, como 100, por exemplo.
  Sem este `IF` teríamos problema ao fazer uma divisão por zero.

Os valores estão sendo retornados em porcentagem. Para retornar o índice numérico apenas, basta remover o `*100` da fórmula.

> [Clique aqui para ver um exemplo funcional no **SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b79b/2)

Baseado no seu código PHP do pastebin, para mostrar o resultado:

```php
$query1 = "SET @anterior=0;";
$query2 = "SELECT id, receitas, despesas, @subtotal := (receitas-despesas) AS subtotal, IF( @anterior !=0, (@subtotal/@anterior-1)*100, '?' ) AS crescimento, @anterior := @subtotal FROM rendimentos;";

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Erro na conexão com o banco de dados");
$db = mysql_select_db($d_b, $conn) or die("Erro na seleção do banco de dados");

$result1 = mysql_query(query1);
$result2 = mysql_query(query2);
echo "<table>";
while ($resultRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
   echo '<tr><td>';
   echo htmlentities($resultRow['id']);
   echo '</td><td>';
   echo htmlentities($resultRow['receitas']);
   echo '</td><td>';
   echo htmlentities($resultRow['despesas']);
   echo '</td><td>';
   echo htmlentities($resultRow['subtotal']);
   echo '</td><td>';
   echo htmlentities($resultRow['crescimento']);
   echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

> IMPORTANTE: Evite usar funções `mysql_`, pois são inseguras e estão obsoletas. O exemplo fornecido foi apenas para poder atender ao que foi solicitado no momento. Recomendo que estude as funções `mysqli_` e converta seu código.

Comment: Show e e para visualizar o valor final da porcentagem em um echo do php?

Comment: @theflash o problema é o seguinte: se você quiser essa relação de crescimento total, precisa dividir os períodos que quer calcular, senão o resultado muda completamente. A taxa de crescimento é de natureza relativa, não basta tirar uma média. Se você quiser total de um ano para outro, por exemplo, teria que calcular a renda do ano passado e a desse, e aplicar a fórmula nesses dois valores. Seria o mesmo princípio da fórmula proposta, mas usando somente os dois totais (em vez de calcular por mês, calcular por ano, por exemplo).

Comment: Obrigado novamente, isto vai ajudar bastante. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi a pergunta, a fórmula para calcular isso é:

> x = receita passada - receita atual / receita passada
>
> receita = x * 100

No link  abaixo, há exemplos mais complexos.

http://pt.wikihow.com/Calcular-Taxa-de-Crescimento

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Porém estou com dúvidas na parte do calculo da porcentagem de crescimento com os valores que estão no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

[Link do SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60a7dc/2/0)

```
<?php
// Proposta utilizando PDO e cálculo do rendimento no PHP

function obterConexaoComOBancoDeDados ($bancoDeDados, $host, $usuario, $senha) {
    $dsn = "mysql:dbname=$bancoDeDados;host=$host";

    try {
        return new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $senha);
    } catch (PDOException $excecao) {
        echo "Falha ao tentar obter uma conexão com o Banco de Dados: {$excecao->getMessage()}";
    }
}

$dbh = obterConexaoComOBancoDeDados("hgsandbox", "localhost", "root", "");

$sql = '
    SELECT
        mes,
        (receita - despesa) AS liquido
    FROM
        Financas
    /* Seria necessário um WHERE?*/
    WHERE
        Usuario_id = :usuarioId
    ORDER BY
        mes
';

$usuarioId = 1; // Id de um usuário.

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':usuarioId', $usuarioId);
$sth->execute();

$linhas = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($linhas as $indice => $linha) {
    if ($indice > 0) {
        $mesAtual = (int) $linha["mes"];
        $valorLiquidoAtual = (float) $linha["liquido"];

        $porcentagemAlteracao = (($valorLiquidoAtual/$valorLiquidoAnterior) - 1) * 100;

        echo "A porcentagem de alteração (crescimento/redução) do mês $mesAnterior para o $mesAtual é de {$porcentagemAlteracao}%.";
    }

   $mesAnterior = (int) $linha["mes"];
   $valorLiquidoAnterior = (float) $linha["liquido"];
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Editei a pergunta ;)

Comment: Obrigado. Realmente ajudou bastante, quais seriam o formato da tabela em .sql por exemplo mês deveria ser vachar, text etc...